# Backbone toJson doesn't return attributes when id is a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am running some rails code to generate json to be consumed by backbone. When I treat the id like a string, and consume it in backbone, the toJSON() function doesn't return the attributes. When I call a to_i on the id, toJSON() works properly. (But this breaks my app because "012345" is different from 12345.

My backbone view:

```
  serialize: ->
      console.log @model.toJSON()
      info: @model.toJSON().info
```

non-working json response:

```
{"id":"123456","info":[{"label":"Hire Date","text":"06-NOV-00"},{"label":"User ID","text":"YADDA"},{"label":"Employee Number","text":"123456"}] }
```

non-working toJSON result:

```
data_partition: DataPartition
id: "123456"
__proto__: Object
```

working json:

```
{"id":123456,"info":[{"label":"Hire Date","text":"06-NOV-00"},{"label":"User ID","text":"YADDA"},{"label":"Employee Number","text":123456}] }
```

working toJSON():

```
data_partition: DataPartition
id: 123456
info: Array[3]
__proto__: Object
```

But this breaks my rails app when I chop off leading 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this code I don't find any issue:

```
var responseJSON_1 = {"id":"123456","info":[{"label":"Hire Date","text":"06-NOV-00"},{"label":"User ID","text":"YADDA"},{"label":"Employee Number","text":"123456"}] };
var responseJSON_2 = {"id":123456,"info":[{"label":"Hire Date","text":"06-NOV-00"},{"label":"User ID","text":"YADDA"},{"label":"Employee Number","text":"123456"}] };

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var myModel_1 = new MyModel( responseJSON_1 );
var myModel_2 = new MyModel( responseJSON_2 );

console.log( myModel_1.toJSON() );
console.log( myModel_2.toJSON() );​
```

Check the [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/WDWUm/)

Are you sure you are not changing more things in your response than the `id` format?

Comment: Looks like the rightmost "text" field also gets unstringified in the working json.  I suspect leading zeroes would be cut off there also.  So yes, more than the id is changing in the example given.

Comment: We never figured this out, but resolved it was something else in our javascript stack. We ended up just using an integer everywhere for consistency, then formatting it to a string with leading 0's where we needed it.